# Get CGPath from Text

Tags: iphone, cgpath, core-text

Hej fellows,

I'm currently trying to convert a letter and/or multiple of them to a CGPathRef for manually drawing them into a custom UIView. I tried the way over CoreText and Framesetters including this little snippet but it doesn't seem to work....

```
NSAttributedString *stringToDraw = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:content
                                                                       attributes:nil];

    // now for the actual drawing
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // flip the coordinate system

    // draw
    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)stringToDraw);
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, NULL);

    return CTFrameGetPath(frame);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CTFrameGetPath` returns the path the circumscribes the `CTFrame`, not the path generated by drawing the frame. I assume that you're doing the above because you are caching the paths to improve later drawing performance? (Since `CTFrame` can easily draw itself into a custom view).

If you really want to get `CGPath`, you need to drill all the way down to the `CGGlyph` and then use `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`. If you just want to quickly redraw text, I'd probably draw this into a `CGLayer` (not `CALayer`) with `CTFrameDraw` for later reuse.

If you still really want the `CGPath` for the glyphs, take a look at [Low-level text rendering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/Glyph.aspx?display=Print). The code you need is in there.