# Inner shadow for cell.textLabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I set inner shadow to cell.textLabel?

Like this:

```
cell.textLabel.innerShadow = xyz(2, 2, #000000);
```

or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that with inner shadows. You basically have to do the drawing yourself and masking out the area outside of the text.

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169119/inner-shadow-in-core-graphics) for the inner shadow part and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447256/get-cgpath-from-text) for getting the path of the text. Then you piece them together so that you draw and mask the inner shadow with the path of you text.